# TAPi18n: How to show text in several languages side by side?

Tags: meteor, internationalization

It seems tapi18n is designed to only have one active language at any given time.

I'm showing a form which includes the same field in several languages. I want to translate the labels and placeholders, because it's useful information for the people filling in the forms, but since I only have access to the current language, I can't show words from others.

I'd like this:

```
## Description ##

English 
[ enter the description ...              ]

Español 
[ enter the description ...              ]

Deutsch 
[ enter the description ...              ]
```

to look like this:

```
## Description ##

English 
[ enter the description ...              ]

Español 
[ introduzca la descripción ...          ]

Deutsch 
[ placeholder in german...               ]
```

I can think of hacks like creating a pre-processor that copies keys like `{ "description_placeholder_$$": "introduzca la description" }` from each json file to every other json file replacing the $$ to the language code, so each language has all the keys containing $$ from every other language.

Another trick would be to load all the json files into memory, independently from tapi18n, and access the required words directly.

Any more elegant ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kyll mentioned, this is how it should work:

```
TAPi18n.__('amusing spaghetti', { lng: 'ru'});
```

But it fails to load languages on demand. As a work around, I preload languages on client side and set a session variable to indicate that all languages have been loaded.

```
var langs = [
  { code: 'en', name: 'English' },
  { code: 'es', name: 'Español' },
  { code: 'de', name: 'Deutsch' }
];

Meteor.startup(function () {
  _.each(langs, function(lang) {
    TAPi18n._loadLanguage(lang.code).done(function() {      
      Session.set('langsLoaded', 
        langs.length == TAPi18n._loaded_languages.length);
    });
  });  
});
```

Then, in a template I have:

```
{{trToLang 'amusing spaghetti' 'ru'}}
```

And finally in a helper:

```
trToLang: function(key, lang) {
  return Session.get('langsLoaded') ? TAPi18n.__(key, { lng: lang }) : ''; 
}
```

The session variable is needed because without it sometimes the languages are not loaded before the template renders, and that breaks TAPi18n.

I hope someone posts a more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but I saw it in use in Sam's md-blog package, maybe it will help to see someone else's implementation?

https://github.com/xolvio/md-blog

HTH

Comment: Thanks, but like most sites, it seems to show just one language at a time. I need a way to show multiple languages at the same time.